# Rendering new row/removing row client side Datatables

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

I have a table that is rendered using DataTables in a cshtml file. I am loading this table client side. I add new rows and delete rows and save the changes using an action that I post to: currently the changes are only shown after a page refresh.

Now I would like my table to reflect those changes without the need for a refresh. It's worth noting that some TD elements in the table have onclick attributes that post and delete data.

Is it possible to update this table client side by using the DataTable API or do I need some sort of server side configuration?

```
   <table id="admin-users-table" class="table">
        @{
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TMUser.DisplayName)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TMUser.GivenName)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TMUser.Surname)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TMUser.CompanyName)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TMUser.AccessLevel)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TMUser.AccessScope)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TMUser.PrismUser)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Remove
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="table-body-admin-users">
                @foreach (var member in Model.CurrentGroupMembers)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => member.DisplayName)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => member.GivenName)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => member.Surname)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => member.CompanyName)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => member.AccessLevel)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => member.AccessScope)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => member.PrismUser)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary delete-user-icon" onclick="RemoveFromGroup('@member.Id','@Model.TMGroup.Id','@member.GivenName','@member.Surname', '@Model.GroupName')">remove</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        }
    </table>
```

> JS function for adding rows to the table/DB.

```
function AddToGroup(groupId, groupName) {
  $("#confirm-add-group").modal('show');
  //post to controller and save to db.
  $.post('/Home/AddToGroup', { userIdList: userIds, groupId: groupId, 
    groupName:groupName 
  });
// add new row here using values group id and group name
}
```

> And removing from the table/DB

```
function RemoveFromGroup(userId, groupId, fName, lName, groupName) {
   $(".confirm-delete").click(function () {
       $.post('/Home/RemoveFromGroup', { userId: userId, groupId: groupId }, function () 
   { });
 });
// remove row here.
}
```

Comment: "_Is it possible to update this table client side by using the DataTable API_" - take a look at the DataTables [`draw()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/draw()) API function.

Comment: I may have mis-read your question - in which case, my apologies. If you want to _change_ data client-side, not just refresh the display, then you can use [row().data()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row().data()) to change data. I don't see where you actually initialize the DataTable anywhere, in the code in the question.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to provide a [mre].